# Is it possible to share revenue with uber intergrated app for every trip of a rider?

Tags: uber-api

I am exploring uber api and i need to found out if such an application can develop which can share rider's revenue with the integrated app on each trip .

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Check out our [affiliate program](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/introduction) for more details about earning with the Uber API.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm a little confused by the wording of "integrated app", but I'll just link the API endpoints you should take a look at to see if they satisfy what you need for developing your own application. If this isn't helpful, just say so and I or someone else will try and help further.

If you want to look at *riders*, the best way I can think of is to use the [history](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get) to get a list of user recent rides and then request a [receipt](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-receipt-get) for every `request_id` in the history.

If you want to look at *drivers*, you can just look at all [earnings](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-payments-get) that are given to a specific driver.

If someone wants to correct me on better ways to do this, feel free.

EDIT: Dustin knows better than me!